# Exception during posting data using Rest easy

Tags: rest, resteasy

When I invoke Post request using rest easy I sometimes get following exception , what could be reason for this ?

```
   javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:102)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:62)

    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:430)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:281)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2024)
        at org.apache.commons.io.output.DeferredFileOutputStream.thresholdReached(DeferredFileOutputStream.java:176)
        at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.checkThreshold(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:224)
        at org.apache.commons.io.output.ThresholdingOutputStream.write(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:128)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.util.DelegatingOutputStream.write(DelegatingOutputStream.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8Generator._flushBuffer(Utf8Generator.java:1748)
```

Comment: **java.io.IOException: No such file or directory**

Comment: Yes but I am just posting some data over HTTP using rest easy. I am not creating any directory myslef.